# Does using constexpr have diminishing returns?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Let's say I have a constexpr int like this:

```
constexpr int i = 42;
```

But so far my program doesn't have any situations in which `i` can be used at compile-time, so it's fairly useless. But in the future, if I want to use `i` in a compile time context, I don't have to backtrack and add `constexpr`. Can this be like const correctness where you put const in the right places and get it "right the first time"? Or is it just unnecessary? What are some negative drawbacks of making everything constexpr?

Comment: Well, it's also **const**, so you can't write `i = 43;` You don't want all you program variables to be const, do you ?

Comment: If you never want to modify the value marking it as a `constexpr` enforces that behavior while also giving you the benefit of using as and array size abd other compile time uses.

Answer (score 0):

The only drawbacks of marking things as `constexpr` are one and the same as the drawbacks of using `constexpr` in the first place.

The two biggest drawbacks that come to mind are that you lose compiler portability (VC++ is very late to the game in terms of supporting `constexpr`) and you can't use "non-trivial" objects in a `constexpr`, such as `std::string`, even though you *can* make them `const`.

Other than that though, there is no particular penalty for using `constexpr` in your code other than the size of the code. If you think it might be useful to use `constexpr` qualified named constants, by all means go ahead. It's a better approach than using preprocessor constants.

Comment: MSVC 19.00.22310.1 (that's version 13.0) compiles `constexpr` just fine.

Comment: I see, The MSDN documentation is lagging then. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx constexpr is still not implemented.

Comment: Well the MSDN documentation is the one that for over 20 years has managed to get entry point of executable, wrong. That said, you're looking at VS 2013 docs, while the compiler I referred ships with VS 2015. Looken Sie bitte here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx